# iphone xml parsing error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

Hello all in my iphone application after sending login xml request am getting following faulted xml... but i cant understand what the error is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor><faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">error in msg parsing:
Charset from HTTP Content-Type &apos;UTF-8&apos; does not match encoding from XML declaration &apos;ISO-8859-1&apos;</faultstring><detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message is saying that you tried to parse a document where the document header said it was encoded in ISO 8859/1, while the HTTP header said it was in UTF-8. Parsers are allowed to resolve that conflict by giving the HTTP header precedence, but it seems this parser chose not to. The inconsistency means there's some kind of configuration problem and it needs to be investigated.

Comment: +1 for you as there is a mismatch in the encoding ,in the XML header there should be UTF-8 encoding as the Objective-c recognize this....